# Why is my wrapper (div) not showing?

Tags: html, css

I need help with my html, I can't seem to find what's causing this, the div with an id of "content wrapper" is not showing up.. I thought of every possible thing that it could be, any ideas?, heres the html + CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>

</header>

<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="top_section">
        <section id="td_left">
            <h1>Hi! I'm Cesar Downs</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="td_right"></section>
    </div>

    <div id="middle_section"></div>

    <div id="bottom_section"></div>


   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

CSS:

```
section {
display: block; }

a {
 text-decoration: none; }

p {
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; }

  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5 {
   font-family: Oswald, sans-serif; }

   #content_wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: red;
   position: absolute; }

   /*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Comment: By `not showing up` you mean you cannot find the div in the source code, or is the content inside not showing?

Comment: not showing up means?? this is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/3epcaocy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you've placed you wrapper element `absolutely` you may need to add the 'exact' location in reference to the nearest parent element whose position is `relative`;

If there isn't one declared, it will automatically align itself to your html tag if i'm not mistaken.

To do this, you would use any (or all) of the following:

```
left:W;
right:X;
top:Y;
bottom:Z;
```

where W,X,Y and Z are values for your positioning (units may vary).

```css
section {
  display: block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
}
#content_wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>

  </header>

  <div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="top_section">
      <section id="td_left">
        <h1>Hi! I'm Cesar Downs</h1>
      </section>
      <section id="td_right"></section>
    </div>

    <div id="middle_section"></div>

    <div id="bottom_section"></div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine [I used internal styling]:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<style>
 section 
{
display: block; }

a {
 text-decoration: none; }

p {
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif; }
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5 {
   font-family: Oswald, sans-serif; }

   #content_wrapper {
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background: red;
   position: absolute; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="top_section">
        <section id="td_left">
            <h1>Hi! I'm Cesar Downs</h1>
        </section>
        <section id="td_right"></section>
    </div>
    <div id="middle_section"></div>
    <div id="bottom_section"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

*Make sure that CSS file is connected properly*